# AGAL undocumented ops

Tags: actionscript-3, agal

While glancing at the source for the AGALMiniAssembler class, I noticed a handful of op codes that don't seem to be documented anywhere - `ifz`, `eif`, `brk`, and a bunch of others - and what look like undocumented texture-sampling flags - `3d`, `centroid`, `single`, and `depth`. Are these working, undocumented operations and flags? Are they unused codes being considered for later implementation? Does anyone know what they do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of them were working with FP 11.6/AIR 3.6 beta (in 'extended' profile) but the support was temporarily dropped in final 11.6 and later versions so you can currently use those opcodes only with 11.6 beta runtime and 11.6 beta playerglobal.swc. Flash [roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html) states that those features will come back sometime this year (AGAL 2.0/MRT support). By the way, you can find more info on new opcodes and other thingies in my [blog](http://nekobit.eu/deferred-shading-extension-for-starling/).